# Confusion related to svm

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svm

I am trying to understand this example related to svm http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/svmclassify.html

I ran the example taking iris data and plotted the svm as given in the example. However, when I view the support vectors in the svmstruct, I get lots of new values. AFAIK, support vectors should be the samples themselves, the ones that lie on the margin. However when I print svmStruct.SupportVectors I get different values like

```
-0.0073   -0.4143
   -0.3706   -0.4143
   -0.2495   -0.1789
   -0.1284    0.2919
   -0.0073   -0.4143
   -0.1284   -0.6498
    0.1139    0.0565
    0.2350   -0.1789
   -0.4918   -0.1789
   -0.2495   -0.4143
   -0.4918    0.0565
    0.1139   -0.4143
   -0.0073    0.2919
   -0.1284    0.2919
   -0.0073    0.2919
    0.2350   -0.4143
    0.8406   -0.6498
   -0.1284    0.2919
    0.2350    0.2919
```

These are not among the sample points. Any clarification

Also I tried to run my own example
and this is what I got.

I don't understand the separating  boundary lies exactly on one of the sample points. I don't think that is the best hyperplane. It should have defined some decision boundary somewhat lower I guess. Also it has circled the support vectors and I am not sure those should be the support vectors. The strangest thing is the margin from the hyperplane to the point is not greater. Why is it so?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know mathworks at all, but according to your link you use the `svmtrain()` function (described [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/bioinfo/ref/svmtrain.html)):

> `SupportVectors` — Matrix of data points with each row corresponding to a support vector in the normalized data space. This matrix is a subset of the Training input data matrix, after normalization has been applied according to the 'AutoScale' argument.

So you datapoints just get normalized. Try setting `autoscale=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, snøreven is right. I just make it more general:

Every ML problem has two stages:

1. Train the model
2. Test/use the trained model

Even better is if you have three stages:

1. Train the model
2. Evaluate the model (is it good enough for my purposes?)
3. Test/use the trained model

[Very short and basic introduction to ML](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlu/mlu_lecture_1.pdf)

[ML course](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml)

In your particular case, you need to train a model for SVM classification in Matlab and then you can use it through the `svmclassify` function.